# Credit card pattern in html

Tags: javascript, html

How can I limited the pattern of credit in 16Numbers and separated in 4 groups and delimited by
either space or dash
like 1234 7896 5678 1234  or 1234/1234/1234/1234
I try this code but it find syntax error

```
cardnumpattern =/[0-9]{4}+\d\s\S[0-9]{4}+\d\s\S[0-9]{4}+\d\s\S[0-9]{4}/
```

Comment: Show your full validation code

Comment: You should state 1. What error it found  2. The exact pattern, format you want, for example is it strictly 16 numbers or at most 16 numbers?

Comment: syntax error was found

Comment: Do note that client-side validation does nothing for security.

Answer (score 1):

If regex is not mandatory, then try a simpler solution

```
var creditCardNumber = "0990-3430-3423-2034"
var isInvalid = creditCardNumber.split(/\s|\-/).filter( function(value){ return isNaN(value) } ).length > 0;

console.log(isInvalid);
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern matches 16 digits, separated by dash or space

```
/^([0-9]{4}( |\-)){3}[0-4]{4}$/
```